# How to deploy/Upgrade Sitefinity site developed in 3.7 SP2, in IIS7 under 4.0 framework?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sitefinity-3x

I have a website developed in Sitefinity 3.7 SP2, that is running successfully on server.
But when I try to run on local system, by Integrating the project in asp.net 4.0 environment. I get following Error:

---

```
 Compilation Error
 Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

 Compiler Error Message: CS0104: 'DynamicHyperLink' is an ambiguous reference between 'Telerik.Cms.Web.UI.DynamicHyperLink' and 'System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicHyperLink'

 Source Error:


 Line 15:             if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
 Line 16:             {
 Line 17:                 DynamicHyperLink link = item.FindControl("dhl") as DynamicHyperLink;
 Line 18:                 if (link != null)
 Line 19:                 {


 Source File: d:\Demo\miamiparking\Sitefinity\ControlTemplates\News\ListPageMaster.ascx    Line: 17


 Show Detailed Compiler Output:


 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

---

Please help me, what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Telerik.Cms.Web.UI.DynamicHyperLink link = 
                  item.FindControl("dhl") as Telerik.Cms.Web.UI.DynamicHyperLink;
```